# How can I set a TClientDataSet's data in the design view?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I have a TClientDataSet object that I've added to my form.

I've managed to define the fields through the object inspector. However, is there a way to define the data the TClientDataSet contains without doing it in code?

I've managed to do it by adding some AppendRecord statements to the ShowForm event; but I'd rather keep the definition of the TClientDataSet all in one place.

Comment: You can e.g. fetch data to some non-client dataset component (still at design time) and then through the right click on your client dataset component use the option [`Assign Local Data`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Assign_Local_Data).

Comment: You can store and load a file into the clientdataset, but you cannot append or edit the data from inside the IDE

Comment: @SirRufo Doesn't this question deserves an answer? Both of you are correct.. the only known way of inserting data into the CDS, in design time, is by the `Assign Local Data` option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to v10.2 (Seattle, Berlin, etc.), there were no facilities to do this.

You can store and load a file into the ClientDataSet or you can use the Assign Local Data (right click on the ClientDataSet) to load data from an existing source. However, you cannot append or edit the data from inside the IDE directly.

As of v10.2 (Tokyo) has recently added this as a feature.

Comment: You can do it in the Delphi Tokyo with TFDMemTable: https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/new-in-10-2-editing-data-in-tfdmemtable-at-design-time